# Error while running a macro from the ribbon

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2010. I've written a code using VBA editor which is used for saving the documents I edit. Basically, it opens the save as file dialog and puts in a name based on a string which is defined by some text in the document and user input via a Inputbox. 
I can successfully run it when I click the view macrocomands tab and execute the macrocomand from there, but if I put a shortcut on a ribbon, the file is instantly saved in C:\Users\Username\Documents with the first line of the document.

```
Sub SaveAs()
'Preia numarul dosarului in numele fisierului

Dim oRng As Range
Dim Nrdosar As String
Dim sTags As String
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Execute FindText:="Dosar nr. ", Forward:=True, _
Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
End With
oRng.Collapse 0
Nrdosar = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, "Dosar nr. ", "")
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, "DOSAR NR. ", "")
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, "/4/", "-")
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, "/", "-")
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, "*", "")
Nrdosar = Replace(Nrdosar, Chr(13), "")
MsgBox Nrdosar
sTags = InputBox("Introduceti cuvinte cheie separate de virgula")
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = Nrdosar & " " & sTags & ".docx"
    .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

I have exported the ribbon shortcuts to try and understand the problem

```
<mso:cmd app="Word" dt="1" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"><mso:ribbon>
<mso:qat><mso:sharedControls>
<mso:control idQ="mso:FileNewDefault" visible="false"/><mso:control idQ="mso:FileOpen" visible="false"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:FileSendAsAttachment" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:FilePrintQuick" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:PrintPreviewAndPrint" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:SpellingAndGrammar" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:TableDrawTable" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:FileOpenRecentFile" visible="false" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:Undo" visible="true" insertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/><mso:control idQ="mso:RedoOrRepeat" visible="true" InsertBeforeQ="mso:FileSave"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:FileSave" visible="true"/>
<mso:button idQ="x1:SaveAs_1" visible="true" label="Normal.NewMacros.SaveAs" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="SaveAs"/>
</mso:sharedControls></mso:qat>
<mso:tabs>
<mso:tab idQ="mso:TabHome">
<mso:group id="mso_c1.-D823CC6" label="Auto" autoScale="true">
<mso:gallery idQ="mso:AutoTextGallery" showInRibbon="false" visible="true"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:TableColumnsDelete" visible="true"/>
<mso:control idQ="mso:TableRowsDelete" visible="true"/>
<mso:button idQ="x1:SaveAs_0_102AE36C" label="Normal.NewMacros.SaveAs" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="SaveAs" visible="true"/>
</mso:group>
</mso:tab><mso:tab id="mso_c1.5F8A243" label="FilÄ nouÄ">
<mso:group id="mso_c2.5F8A243" label="Grup nou" autoScale="true">
<mso:control idQ="mso:DateAndTimeInsert" visible="true"/>
</mso:group>
</mso:tab>
</mso:tabs>
</mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

I cannot imagine why the result is different when running the macrocomand from the View Macrocomands tab versus the shortcut that I put in a ribbon.

I believe that there is no problem with the VBA code itself and that there is some kind of a bug. 
I would like to be able to run the VBA code using a shortcut. 
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem or bug was in the name of the Macro. I have changed the first line from:

> Sub SaveAs()

to

> Sub SaveDoc()

I still don't understand this behavior, but I wanted to share the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveAs` is a built-in command in Word (as in File/Save As). So sending the command to run a macro with this name is by-passing the actual macro and executing Word's built-in command.

Assigning a different name (non-reserved) to the macro should fix the problem.